# Compiler error for obsolete COMType using DirectShow

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, directshow, webcam-capture

I am coding a small app that takes a users picture to be printed on an ID card. I have looked around and found a number of different examples of this in `C#` that would be perfect for me to use except for 2 issues both attaining to a `UCOM` element now being obsolete in the newer `.NET` frameworks.

This is the code that gives the error:

```
int hr = devEnum.CreateClassEnumerator(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, out classEnum, CDef.None);
```

And this is the exact wording of the error:

> Error 2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumMoniker' to 'out
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.UCOMIEnumMoniker'  E:\Programming\Application
>   Files\WebCamControl2\WebCamControl2.cs    108 89  WebCamControl2

I am using the DirectShow dll that was last used in 2005 and it uses a `UCOMIEnumMoniker` and `UCOMIMoniker` that have been changed to `IEnumMoniker` and `IMoniker` respectively.

How can i get around this compile error? Can I cast the newer type as the old one even if its obsolete or do I have to scrap the idea of using the DirectShow lib?

Comment: "that have been changed".  The exception tells you that they haven't been changed.  You are still using the old DLL.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds if you have no idea how this happened.  Beware of it being in the GAC and forgetting to increase the [AssemblyVersion].

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally deal with `UCOMxxx` types unless you are working with ancient .NET versions. From DirectShow.NET source:

```
#if USING_NET11
            [Out] out UCOMIEnumMoniker ppEnumMoniker,
#else
            [Out] out IEnumMoniker ppEnumMoniker,
#endif
```

You should find out where you get `UCOMIEnumMoniker` in your project exactly, and most likely it should not be there.